# How to call a curl command in Angular using httpClient

Tags: angular, rest, curl

I have a curl command which uploads a .zip file to the nexus repository. I want to call this command in Angular. I am wondering how it has to be done. Can you please help me out.
command:
curl -v -u username:password --upload-file test.zip http://use08nexus01p:8081/nexus/content/repositories//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl's --upload-file parameter uses a PUT request to xfer the data to your server.  The -u parameter uses basic authentication.  There are a lot of ways you could send a similar request using Angular.  You will likely have a service that does this work for you.  Below is one possible way to accomplish this.  Note that the service function below returns an observable that will need to be subscribed to in a component.  Perhaps  something like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpParams, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public uploadFile(file: File, username: string, password: string): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      // Note - this returns an EVENT, so we can track progress
      var headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(`${username}:${password}`));
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('upload', file);
      const params = new HttpParams;
      const options = { headers: headers, params: params, reportProgress: true };
      const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', 'http://use08nexus01p:8081/nexus/content/repositories/', formData, options);
      return this.http.request(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give a try!

Comment: Angular :   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
Angular electron  : I am getting 500 server error.

Comment: errror :
e {headers: t, status: 500, statusText: "Server Error", url: "http://use08nexus01p:8081/nexus/content/repositories/test/Veda/", ok: false…}error: nullheaders: tmessage: "Http failure response for http://use08nexus01p:8081/nexus/content/repositories/test/Veda/: 500 Server Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 500statusText: "Server Error"url: "http://use08nexus01p:8081/nexus/content/repositories/test/Veda/"

Comment: This is not an angular error.  See this: https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/  Description of what CORS is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.  Would suggest you search on stackoverflow for the new issue you're running into or start a new question to resolve.

Comment: I am getting 500 server error for the http request, Am I missing here something while sending the request?

Comment: Again, I suggest you start a new question.  For that question if you could post what you are doing in Stackblitz or equivalent it would help people to assist you in troubleshooting the issue you are running into.

Comment: This solution works perfectly fine! I made some mistake in file while calling the function. I was able to resolve it and this solution to upload file to nexus works as expected . Thanks @dmcgrandle

Comment: Its doesn't work for me. I get a 404 not found. It works fine if I use fetch so its not CORS